# What's the most efficient way to overlap two images using CSS on Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is my first WordPress development and I just wanted to know how I can get two images to overlap the cover image using CSS.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few alteration and adons in css , you can achieve the design

```
 .primary-navigation ul {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: -42px; /*Added*/
    }
.primary-navigation a {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 0px 20px;            /**Changed**/
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }

    /*new css*/
    li#menu-item-29 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```